# Switching between posts (Goes through all posts?) PHP

Tags: php

Hello I have kind of a step-voting system, so when you click on continue, it goes to the next step.
I do not want to use sessions, therefore I am using POST to go to the next step and queries to call items.

```
if (isset($_POST['continue']))
{
    if ($_POST['vote_page'] == 'site1')
    {
        $_POST['vote_page'] = 'site2';

    }

    if ($_POST['vote_page'] == 'site2')
    {
        $_POST['vote_page'] = 'site3';      

    }   
}
```

if clicked continue and at site 1, then go to site 2, etc.

```
switch ($_POST['vote_page'])
{

case 'site1':
echo 'site1!';
break;

case 'site2':
echo 'site 2!!';
break;

case 'site3':
echo 'site 3!!!!!';
break;

}
```

But for some reason it loops through all of these posts, because the PHP is on the top of the script I think.

**Problem:**

From site1, it went to site3, ignoring site2...

How can I prevent this? or is there any other way to manage step-voting without sessions?

Comment: You want to use *else-if* statements, rather than a series of *if* statements.  Currently, if the post value is `site1`, it is set to `site2`, which is then checked immediately after, causing it to be set to `site3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies or hidden input tags to transmit data and you can use $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] to know your current location, I see you're French so I'm going to say '**Bon chance!**'

Comment: Nono, I am russian ;-), I rather not to use either cookies or hidden inputs. That way the user can easily remove them. But would it be possible if I add all of these voting sites into columns and then mark ( 0 =not voted , 1 = voted), if site1 == 0, show site1, else show site 2 etc?

Comment: You can do that I guess (don't forget to include the user ID or something in that table)